# Ansible - split string inserted by user

Tags: ansible

I'm creating a playbook to run commands on Junos OS. So it goes like this:

```
  vars_prompt:
    - name : "text"
      prompt: "Type your text"
      private: no
```

So the user will probably write something like:

```
"show log | match TEST"
```

After that, my variable "text" will have "show log | match TEST". What I would like to do is to be able to split this string into:

```
show log
match TEST
```

And put this result in another variable, like

```
TEST1 = "show log"
TEST2 = "match TEST"
```

So I can work with those variables separated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `split` function for this:

```
- set_fact:
    test1: "{{  text.split('|')[0] }}"
    test2: "{{  text.split('|')[1] }}"
  when: "|" in text
```

Please note that this is only going to set the variables if the `text` variable contains a `|` symbol.

Comment: So is there any way I can make a condition for it? Like, when TEXT has a "|" set the fact!

Comment: I've added a "when" condition to my answer.